# With embedded jetty, do you still need to install jetty on the server?

Tags: java, jetty

When you deploy a web app (servlets) with embedded jetty, do you still need to install jetty on the server?

How do you start/stop jetty when it is embedded?  You also have to consider when the server reboots.

Just confused on the deployment aspect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you deploy a web app (servlets) with embedded jetty, do you still need to install jetty on the server?

No there is nothing to install. The server should be contained with your application.

> How do you start/stop jetty when it is embedded? You also have to consider when the server reboots

You have to stop or start you application. You can kill the process. Doing `ctrl + c` should kill the application. Read more about this mode at jetty's [website](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty).

Answer (score 1):

If Jetty is embedded then the application starts the server itself so you don't need to install it on the server. You start Jetty by starting the application, this may vary from application to application. You certainly should install the application as service on the server so it will be automatically started when the servers reboots.

Take for example [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) which utilizes an embedded server but can also be deployed to a servlet container. [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-running.html) uses the same strategy.